# Regular Expression Validator on address email in c#

Tags: c#, regex, email

I need check if the address email is correct in markup of my aspx page.

The possible address email correct is :

> Name(AndAnyNumber).Surname(AndAnyNumber)@march.com

And I have tried this **RegularExpressionValidator** :

```
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="retxtEmail" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
     ErrorMessage="Not valid" Text="Not valid" Display="Dynamic" 
     ValidationExpression="^([a-z][a-z0-9]*\\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*@march\\.com)$"  
     SetFocusOnError="true" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Withou success because for address email :

> tom.shepard2@march.com

The return is **Not valid**, why ?

Can you please help me figure out the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hm, curious, try `"^([a-z][a-z0-9]*[.][a-z][a-z0-9]*@march[.]com)$"`

Comment: I guess it will be due to the double escaped backslash. You _do_ need to escape the `.`, but try with just the single slash. If that still doesn't work (for example, if asp.net adds the second slash for you) try @WiktorStribiżew suggestion above to escape using `[.]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your `regex`.Replace your `regex` with this:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+@march\.com)$
```

if numbers are not mandatory replace `[0-9]+` with `[0-9]*`

Comment: Then his email can start with a number, which he doesn't want

Comment: Your `^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+.[a-zA-Z0-9]+@march.com)$` regex  now allows the user part and domain part without a dot.

Comment: This pattern doesn't match the provided example - not sure why it's been accepted?

Answer (score 1):

This regex has been tested as working using Regex Coach (a good free tool for writing regex's).

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9]*\.[a-z][a-z0-9]*@march\.com$
```

Issues are:

**Using**

- No need for the capturing parentheses
- Currently case sensitive. Email addresses tend not be be.
- Double back slashes - this is what was causing issues for me though this   might be ASP.NET thing

Comment: There must be a problem with your Tool.Regex is not working.

Comment: No, the formatting on SO was eating characters. Neededed to change it to be a code snippit for it to include all charatcers. Code now fixed.